# Pygame Object Movement

Tags: python, pygame

I have two objects that I control with my keboard, one with WASD and the other with the arrows. (Imagine a 2D game)

I recently made the code to make them keep moving while the key is pressed but if I keep pressing W and up arrow at the same time only one works and the other one stops.
 I would like to know a fix.

This is the movement code:

```
if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

    if e.key==K_d:
        PX += movimentenpx
        EnergiaD +=energiapermoviment

    if e.key==K_a:
        PX -= movimentenpx
        EnergiaD +=energiapermoviment

    if e.key==K_w:

        PY -= movimentenpx
        EnergiaD +=energiapermoviment

    if e.key==K_s:

        PY += movimentenpx
        EnergiaD +=energiapermoviment

    if e.key ==K_UP:

        PY2 -= movimentenpx
        EnergiaD2 +=energiapermoviment

    if e.key ==K_LEFT:
        PX2 -= movimentenpx

        EnergiaD2 +=energiapermoviment

    if e.key ==K_DOWN:

        PY2 += movimentenpx
        EnergiaD2 +=energiapermoviment

    if e.key ==K_RIGHT:
        PX2 +=movimentenpx
        EnergiaD2 +=energiapermoviment
```

Comment: You might need to get a better keyboard.

Comment: I just tryed it and it has nothing to do with the type of keyboard.

Comment: Can you post the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grabbing the key presses from `for event in pygame.event.get():` will only get you one key press at a time. you need to use `pygame.key.get_pressed()` to grab the array of that state of the entire keyboard.

```
pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if pressed_keys[pygame.K_w]:
    # do stuff
if pressed_keys[pygame.K_s]:
    # do stuff
```

This all happens in the main game loop. This is also the way to grab the keys if you want to hold down keys.

For more documentation: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed

Comment: if pressed_keys[pygame.K_w]:
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: ah, i was using `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()` instead of `pygame.key.get_pressed()`. I updated my answer

Comment: but also note you can do the same thing with multiple mouse clicks with `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()`

Comment: I noticed that, I already have a fix tho but thanks for your help.